# Calling Javascript function AND a function in codebehind when radiobutton changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, code-behind

I have a Javascript function I want to call and pass the value of the selected radio buttton.

My button which calls a function in the code behind:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtLocation" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                    RepeatLayout="Table" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbtLocation_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Is there a way to trigger a second call to a javascript function since I am already calling one function on change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try out using jquery like `$('element_ID').on('change'){function func1(){/*code here*/};`
or you may add you javascript function to CodeBehind, to function *rbtLocation_SelectedIndexChanged*. It will looks like

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>/* javascript function */</script>");
```